# Comparison of JSON Parser for Objective-C (JSON Framework, YAJL, TouchJSON, etc)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

As far as I know, there are three JSON Parsers for Objective-C, [JSON Framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/), [YAJL](http://github.com/gabriel/yajl-objc), and [Touch JSON](http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/wiki/TouchJSON). Then, These three would have their own characteristics.

For example:
YAJL can be used as a SAX style parser.
JSON Framework has relatively long history and is widely used.
Touch JSON parses NSData instead of NSString.

In addition, as far as I tested, the result of performance comparison is as follows:
[fast] **YAJL > JSON Framework > Touch JSON** [slow].

If you know pros and cons of these JSON parsers, could you tell me?
Lastly, if you know any other JSON Parser, please tell me.

Comment: My vote up! This is a great question. Would love some experts answer this one. I have been using JSON Framework all along but ya, am eager to know the pros and cons of other parsers.

Comment: Thanks Chintan. I'm also using JSON Framework and have no complain. But, I hope someone could give us a good answer.

Comment: What about a streaming JSON parser for Obj-C? I'd like to have a parser that would tell it's delegate when a new object has been parsed, e.g. when you're downloading a large JSON from a server, you could start processing the part which has been received. It might also lower the memory footprint.

Comment: YAJL would be exactly what you want. http://rel.me/2009/06/15/yajl-json-parser-objective-c-bindings/

Comment: FYI Touch JSON has moved to: http://github.com/schwa/touchcode

Comment: A comprehensive [review](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/json-versus-plist-the-ultimate-showdown/).

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you're looking for speed, take a look at [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit).  It is (usually) much faster than the already mentioned JSON libraries, often an order of magnitude faster.  And because of it's "recently instantiated object cache", it will (again, usually) use less memory as well.

Comment: I can confirm this :) In my tests, JSONKit was almost twice faster than YAJL and 50% faster than JSON Framework, but apparently the data I used for the test was a kind of worst case scenario for JSONKit.

Comment: Second that. Remember to set the NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS flag in your Release builds. It even further improves the speed.

Comment: AFAICT JSONKit does not support stream-based parsing, so if that's an issue you might want to go with json-framework or YAJL.

Comment: JSONKit for performance. Referece: a comprehensive [review](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/json-versus-plist-the-ultimate-showdown/) by cocoanetics.com.

Comment: One thumb up for JSONKit. One project was using JSON Framework before, sometimes it just failed to parse a big JSON data, my guess is memory problem.

Comment: I vote for JSONKit as well ([look at this comparison](http://www.bonto.ch/blog/2011/12/08/json-libraries-for-ios-comparison-updated/))

Comment: In iOS 6, `NSJSONSerialization` seems to be faster but for pre-iOS 6 devices, JSONKit definitely wins.

Comment: As of right now, it looks like JSONKit has been abandoned by the author. There's some issues with the latest version of XCode, numerous pull requests to fix it, and none of them have been accepted.

Comment: @ohno - Here's the direct link to the previously mentioned review on cocoanetics.com, http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/json-versus-plist-the-ultimate-showdown/

Comment: The major problem with JSONKit is that it doesn't support ARC or projects that use ARC and apparently there are no plans to. https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit#important-details

Answer (score 12):

Considering [a comparison that I did](http://www.bonto.ch/blog/2011/12/08/json-libraries-for-ios-comparison-updated/), the fastest library is JSONKit, followed by NSJSONSerialization (now public API) and NextiveJSON. SBJSON and TouchJSON are a little bit slower than the previous 3 libraries.

The comparison has been done using an iPhone 4S with iOS 5.0.1.

Comment: Up-vote for mentioning that NSJSONSerialization is part of the public API! I will stick with this, because there won't be any trouble with maintenance.

Comment: ditto. [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html), for me, is the sensible way to go - at least for targetting iOS 5.0 and up.

Comment: Link in answer is broken. Please fix it

Answer (score 5):

There's also [this parser](http://github.com/sazameki/json-objc-parser):

I don't remember how I stumbled upon this one, but it looked lightweight and simple, so I thought that it suits my needs. I event forked it in order to add initialization from NSData.
As I needed to parse small responses, I didn't care about the performance. It would be interesting to know how it performs though.

Comment: This is the most lightweight and simple JSON parser I've used so far, highly recommended.

Comment: Wow, made my day. Such a simple and elegant parser!

Answer (score 3):

I think JSONKit is faster than YAJL and YAJL is faster than Touch JSON and IOS5 class NSJSONSerialization class is much faster. [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) have no need to use any third party APIs.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [this post](http://mackuba.eu/2010/03/04/cocoa-json-parsing-libraries/). <30 characters>

Comment: Even better, see the updated version here http://psionides.jogger.pl/2010/12/12/cocoa-json-parsing-libraries-part-2/ (spoiler: JSONKit wins).

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a look at akosma's benchmarks on parsers where he compares different kinds of parsers. If one parser is missing, you might as well add it to the tests, since his code is open source.

[iPhoneWebServicesClient](https://github.com/akosma/iPhoneWebServicesClient)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a serializer from NSObject to JSON and vice versa, you might want to checkout [OBJC JSONSerializer](https://github.com/mahadevans87/OBJC_JSONSerializer)