# What's the best way to connect iPhone app (iOS SDK) to php/MySql backend

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, web-applications

New to iPhone dev here. Just wondering what's the best way to connect an iPhone app frontend  (based on Cocoa) to a php/MySql based backend?

The iPhone application will frequently access and change data stored on our server.

Many thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to connect to a MySQL database from an iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468618/how-to-connect-to-a-mysql-database-from-an-iphone)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to create a web service that will expose a set of APIs that are then use by your iPhone app to push/pull data. You may then choose to cache the data locally (on the iPhone) in a sqlite3 database.
The most common data transfer formats are JSON and XML.

Comment: Further to your answer here is link to JSON library for iPhone: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025349/is-there-an-3rd-party-library-for-parsing-json-on-the-iphone/4025379#4025379

Comment: For a discussion on the best JSON library see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286087/best-json-library-to-use-when-developing-an-iphone-application . I use json-framework.

Comment: Thanks guys, any resources for XML? (for comparison)

Comment: There is TouchXML (part of the touchcode project). http://github.com/schwa/TouchCode

Comment: If you're creating something from scratch anyway, I'd go with JSON, it's much faster to transfer and parse. Binary plists are also awesome :)

Comment: Thanks for all your comments guys, will get into JSON pretty soon.