# Three20 + JSON Parsing

Tags: iphone, three20

I'm using Three20 and want to use JSON to populate my `TTPhotoViewController`.

If I go to a web address, let's say,

```
www.bbc.com/jsonoutput
```

I get the following

```
{"name":"MyName","curNiceDate":"Wed 29 Dec 10","images":["UK\/2010\/12\/29\/1.jpg","US\/2010\/12\/29\/2.jpg","EU``\/2010\/12\/29\/3.jpg","FR\/2010\/12\/29\/4.jpg","FR\/2010\/12\/29\/5.jpg","FR\/2010\/12\/29\/6.jpg","FR\/2010\/12\/29\/7.jpg","FR\/2010\/12\/29\/8.jpg","FR\/2010\/12\/29\/9.jpg"]}
```

I want to pick out images which are in `www.bbc.com/images/`.

All those directories are locations of images relevant from the above address. How would I go about pulling out this information from the JSON output and make it into a URL which will look like this

```
www.bbc.com/UK/2010/12/29/1.jpg

www.bbc.com/US/2010/12/29/2.jpg

www.bbc.com/EU/2010/12/29/3.jpg

www.bbc.com/FR/2010/12/29/4.jpg
```

So I can feed it into the TTPhotoView Picker.

Any help please?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256625/comparison-of-json-parser-for-objective-c-json-framework-yajl-touchjson-etc) for information on the various JSON libraries.  I happen to be the author of [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/stig/json-framework  It's super easy to use.  If you get stuck just look at how I used it in my code [here](https://github.com/computermatt/MSOEngine/blob/master/MSOEngine.m)

Comment: Thanks, I was told Three20 has its own JSON Parser, or is it better to import another one?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/three20/tree/master/src/extThree20JSON . Trying to use this to do the above

Comment: It uses the same framework to do it... https://github.com/facebook/three20/tree/master/src/extThree20JSON/Vendors/JSON

Answer (score 3):

I've been happy with [TouchJSON](https://github.com/schwa/TouchJSON), it's also very easy to use. I'm using it in conjunction with [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest).

Here's a quick modification of my code to relate to your question.

```
- (IBAction)getImages{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.bbc.com/jsonoutput"];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *bbcData = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:[request responseData] error:&error];
    //TODO: do something with the error
    NSArray *images = [bbcData objectAtIndex:@"images"]; 
    NSLog(@"%@", images);   
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{
    NSError *error = [request error];
    //TODO: do something with the error
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! It really helped as i have a better idea now!

I was told that Three20 has its own JSON Parser, trying to use that parser instead of importing another one, but struggling

Comment: Ah cool, good to know. I have't used the Three20 framework yet.

Answer (score 0):

json-framework is good use it.