# objective-c JSON parser comparison: which is easier to use?

Tags: objective-c, json, comparison

I've seen the comparison thread on objective-c JSON parsers here: [Comparison of JSON Parser for Objective-C (JSON Framework, YAJL, TouchJSON, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256625/comparison-of-json-parser-for-objective-c-json-framework-yajl-touchjson-etc) but can someone offer their opinions on which is the easiest/simplest to setup and to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer [json-framework](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/)  simply because it just works =) 
Here is how to parse:

```
NSObject* parsed_obj = [[[[SBJsonParser alloc] init] autorelease] objectWithData: data];
```

And that's all!

`parsed_obj` could be NSArray or NSDictionary. You should check this using `iskindOfClass:` method. And then you work with with simple containers. BTW it has convenient categories for NSDictionary, NSArray, NSData in the later release.

Comment: I find it ironic that you cite json-framework for its ease-of-use, but don't use the `-[NSString JSONValue]` method as your example :)

Comment: @Dave DeLong  i've copied an example from my old project where i had to parse data received from web server.