# iOS: Deserializing JSON in separate thread?

Tags: iphone, multithreading, ios, json, deserialization

I am currently using the TouchJSON library in my iOS app. I currently deserialize JSON on the main thread and this seems to work well. The Earthquakes XML example in the iOS Developer Library demonstrates XML parsing on a secondary thread and I'm wondering if this would be a good idea for deserialization from JSON as well? My JSON objects are small so it seems unnecessary. What do you think?

Comment: Test on the slowest device you support (e.g. the original iPhone for iOS 3+, iPhone 3GS for iOS 4+) and see if performance is an issue.  The most likely place where you'll notice this is while scrolling a table view -- if deserialization takes more than say 50 ms, you'll probably notice some jumpy scrolling animation.

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible, however, start the performance tuning only if you need it. So many sins have been commited in the name of perfomance optimization!

Have a look at [Comparison of JSON Parser for Objective-C (JSON Framework, YAJL, TouchJSON, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256625/comparison-of-json-parser-for-objective-c-json-framework-yajl-touchjson-etc) for some discussion about performance of the various frameworks.

Here's a [review about the performance of the different frameworks](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/json-versus-plist-the-ultimate-showdown/), also linked in the Q&A I posted above:

[image]