# Putting JSON into an Array

Tags: ios, json, ios6, nsarray, afnetworking

I'm a noob when it comes to requests and JSON. Inside my app I send to the server and get back stuff so I can use it of course. I tried looking up different things but none really seem to be what I'm looking for. So I'm getting back what seems to be formatted JSON. What I want to know how to do is put it into a NSMutable array. The way I get this JSON is by using AFNetworking's AFJSONRequestOperation.

My response looks like this.

```
{
    id = 38;
    name = "St. Martin Hall";
},
    {
    id = 40;
    name = "Assumptions Commons";
},
    {
    id = 41;
    name = "Vickroy Hall";
},
    {
    id = 42;
    name = "St. Ann Hall";
},
    {
    id = 37;
    name = "Duquesne Towers";
}
```

Comment: `NSJSONSerialization` class reference, please...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your JSON format like {"mainKey":[{},{},...]}

```
 NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization 
        JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1
         options:kNilOptions 
        error:&error];

    NSArray* dataArray = [json objectForKey:@"mainKey"]; //2
```

else your JSON format like [{},{},...]

```
NSError* error;
    NSArray* dataArray = [NSJSONSerialization 
        JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1
        options:kNilOptions 
        error:&error];
```

I think your format is case 2: [] Array of Object {}

Tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

JSON:http://www.json.org

Comment: Thanks! The tutorial really showed me what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> You use the `NSJSONSerialization` class to convert JSON to Foundation objects and convert Foundation objects to JSON.

This class is available in iOS 5.0+. If you're targetting older iOS version, have a look at a third-party JSON framework:

[Comparison of JSON Parser for Objective-C (JSON Framework, YAJL, TouchJSON, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256625/comparison-of-json-parser-for-objective-c-json-framework-yajl-touchjson-etc)

Answer (score 0):

If that's what you're getting back it's not JSON I'm afraid. It does look like Javascript in a way but it should be more like

```
[
  {
     "id" : 38,
     "name" : "St. Martin Hall"
  },
  {
     "id" : 39,
     "name" : "Assumptions Commons"
  }
]
```

Comment: That is how is coming back. I just didn't put the [ and ]

Comment: and the : vs =, and the , instead of ;

Comment: I did it a new way and now it comes back as you posted.