# How to get an array of JSON objects from NSData object

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, swift, nsdata

So I'm using an HTTP GET method which returns an array of JSON objects, which are stored in NSData.  The array looks like this:

```
[{"created_at":"2013-03-09T04:55:21Z","data_type":"image","id":5354,"latitude":37.785834,"longitude":-122.406417,"name":"tempObject","privacy":"public","radius":1000.0,"updated_at":"2013-03-09T04:55:21Z","user_id":101},{"created_at":"2013-03-10T20:57:08Z","data_type":"image","id":5364,"latitude":37.785834,"longitude":-122.406417,"name":"tempObject","privacy":"public","radius":1000.0,"updated_at":"2013-03-10T20:57:08Z","user_id":101}]
```

How would I go about extracting these JSON objects and iterate through them from the NSData?

Comment: Did you try searching "ios json nsdata"? It seems to turn up any number of already-answered questions on that exact topic...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180036/putting-json-into-an-array/15181743#15181743

Comment: The "This question already has an answer here" did not give me the adequate answer. I need some practical answer like the answer on this page. This question is not a duplicate from the one on the top.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

If you're using iOS 5.0 and up, you can do this:

Objective-C:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myNSData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

if (error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON.");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Array: %@", jsonArray);
}
```

Swift:

```
do {
    let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: myNSData, options:[])
    print("Array: \(jsonArray)")
}
catch {
    print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: Was missing something. Fixed! Sorry about that.